Identify this larger castle similar to Medieval Castle 31120
I purchased this set second-hand, and unfortunately the castle fell apart while boxing it up.  It looks similar in style to Medieval Castle 31120, especially the red and white banners, and the gatehouse above the drawbridge, but it is distinctly different.  There are more towers, including two towers with cannons atop them.  The gatehouse windows are arched rather than square,   There's a distinctive blue "shingled" roof composed of different shades of blue.

The shield above the gate has a lion's head:

Any idea what set this is, and where I can find the build instructions?

I'm baffled by this one. The brown 2x2 maraconi tiles would suggest set 10305, and the pentagonal blue roof tiles would suggest set 21325. But I cannot find a pentagonal tile with that lion head (see https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Tile+Pentagonal+lion ), and I cannot find any yellow 3x3x6 corner panels with that sticker/print with cracks. Can you please check if there are "lego" or "mega" markings on the bricks?

Also, part https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22409 is not available in grey/silver.

I think this is Reobrix 66006 European Century Golden Lion Castle


I think that's definitely it.  I never heard of Reobrix but I guess I'm now an owner.  Any idea where to get the instructions?

Instructions can be found here yourwobb
under Other
